# Grouping URLs for Re-Writing

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

Pretty new to re-write rules. Trying to group these:

```
/Brands/Lee/c/Lee
/Brands/Lee
```

To go here:

```
/Lee
```

This:

```
Rewrite Rule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $2/ [R=301]
```

Is too simple as it ignores other sections of the site

This rule:

```
Rewrite Rule ^brands/(.*)$ $1/ [R=301]
```

Doesn't capture the /c/ URL

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^Brands/((.*)/c/)?(.*)$ /$3 [R=301]
```

Comment: Modified slightly and on the money: RewriteRule ^.rands/((.*)/c/)?(.*)$ /$3 [R=301]